# How to Implement the Sparse matrix in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, sparse-matrix

Hear I'm taking user input for matrix

```
print("Enter values for matrix ")
a = []
m = int(input("Number of rows, m = "))
n = int(input("Number of columns, n = "))

for i in range(m):
    l = []
    for j in range(n):
        l.append(int(input("Entry in row: {} column: {}\n".format(i+1,j+1))))
    a.append(l)

print("Matrix - =",a)
```

if user input is
Enter values for matrix
Number of rows, m = 2
Number of columns, n = 3
Entry in row: 1 column: 1
1
Entry in row: 1 column: 2
2
Entry in row: 1 column: 3
3
Entry in row: 2 column: 1
4
Entry in row: 2 column: 2
5
Entry in row: 2 column: 3
6
Matrix - = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

I'm trying to sparse Matrix to print
Sparse Matrix:
001
012
023
104
115
126

Comment: You just showed the way you're getting the matrix elements from user, please show what you have done to make a sparse matrix.

Comment: The whole point of a sparse matrix is that you don't loop through (or store or otherwise handle) all the elements, only the non-zero ones

Answer (score 1):

To use the sparse matrix in python, simply install
[scipy library](https://www.scipy.org/).
Following is an example of how to use it with numpy.

```
# Load libraries
import numpy as np

from scipy import sparse

# Create a matrix
matrix = np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[3,0]])

# Create a compressed sparse row (CSR) matrix
matrix_sparse = sparse.csr_matrix(matrix)

# View sparse matrix 
print(matrix_sparse)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add row, column values also to the 'l' variable and then reset it inside the second loop. Append 'l' should happen in second loop

```
print("Enter values for matrix ")
a = []
m = int(input("Number of rows, m = "))
n = int(input("Number of columns, n = "))

for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        l = []
        l.append(i)
        l.append(j)
        l.append(int(input("Entry in row: {} column: {}\n".format(i+1,j+1))))
        a.append(l)

print("Matrix - =",a)
```

output

```
Matrix - = [[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 3], [1, 0, 4], [1, 1, 5], [1, 2, 6]]
```

Comment: This is neither a sparse matrix nor handled as a sparse matrix?

Comment: I was trying to match the output required by OP. I understand its not sparse matrix but my attempt was only to produce the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better approach to get the matrix values.

```
rows, cols = map(int, input("Enter the number of rows and columns").split())
matrix = []

for i in range(rows):
    matrix.append(list(map(int, input("Enter the row values").split())))

for i in matrix:
    print(*i, sep="", end=" ")
```

Comment: This is neither a sparse matrix nor handled as a sparse matrix?